# Convert Office Interop image attachment to OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

Convert adding remote image to word document from Interop to OpenXML and DocumentFormat classes.

We currently use Office Interop to open/edit/save and send word, excel and ppt documents but now need to move to OpenXML to create these using "DocumentFormat" classes.  Mostly has gone well apart from the requirement to add a reference to an external image into the document.

Currently we use the following to include the external ref :-

```
if (f.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldIncludePicture)
{
   Range code = f.Code;
   code.Text = "INCLUDEPICTURE \\d \"https://" + Domain + "/" + UID + "\" \\* MERGEFORMATINET";
   f.UpdateSource();
}
```

But can't work out how to do the same using DocumentFormat classes.

Would appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you create a document containing only this kind of field (keep it small). Open it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and inspect the XML as well as the code that would create the document. Inspect the code that creates the field to understand how Word manages this "under the covers". Then change the link and save the changed document to a new name. Use the Tool again to compare the original document with the changed one to see the code used to make the change.